# Defining the User roles in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Android app with ***Firebase as backend***, I am planning to have three roles based on Security. `User`, `Editor`, `Administrator`

Anyone signing-up using Facebook is granted the User role by default.

- The User can read anything but has very limited write permissions (`provide reviews`).
- The Editor can read anything and has more write permissions than the user (`create articles, provide reviews`).
- The Administrator can `create/Delete Editors`.

The Administrator can upgrade the role of an User to an Editor and vice-versa.
Hence creating the User roles and Editor roles is taken care of. **But, how to create an Administrator in the first place?**

Regards

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what makes someone an administrator. If you want to explicitly manage the list of administrators up front, you could simply look them up in the Firebase Console and copy their `uid` into your security rules.

```
".write": "auth.uid == 'theUidThatYouLookedUp"
```

Or one level better would be to keep a read-only list of administrator in the database and refer to that in the rule:

```
".write": "root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()"
```

But often there is something in the app that determines whether someone is an administrator. E.g.: the creator of a chat room is its administrator. In this case you'd store the admin for that chat room when you create the chat room.

```
"chatRooms": {
  "$chatRoomId": {
    ".write": "root.child('chatRoomOwners').child($chatRoomId).val() == auth.uid"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The role of the Admin, in my case, is only to add/remove Editors who can create articles. The Admin cannot be auto-generated. Hence, the third option can be ruled out.

Comment: Your first option is very simple. Since the number of Admins is going to be very little, working with this option won't be an issue. However, this doesn't help for adding Editors (although adding Editors was not a part of the question, but just for the argument) as there will be more Editors compare to Admins. Looking into the Console for every Editor will be little tedious - hence will be of no help for adding editors. Using a separate node for `admins` or `Editors` seems good. But again, how to add users to the `admins` or `Editors` node?. I am sorry if my question is too basic to ask.

Comment: The way that Frank has the admins node in the database and does the child exists, you want to do that for the editors. You don't want it to be read-only though so within your app when you control the creation/removing editors you would want to update the database node and add the auth.uid for the editor.

The rule however remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Firebase just launched support for role based access on any user via custom user claims on the ID token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

You would define the admin access rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "adminContent": {
      ".read": "auth.token.role === 'admin'",
      ".write": "auth.token.role === 'admin'",
    }
  }
}
```

Set the user role with the Admin SDK:

```
// Set admin privilege on the user corresponding to uid.
admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, {role: 'admin'}).then(() => {
  // The new custom claims will propagate to the user's ID token the
  // next time a new one is issued.
});
```

This will propagate to the corresponding user's ID token claims.

To parse it from the token on the client, you need to base64 decode the ID token's payload.

You can upgrade/downgrade users as needed. Setting editor role follows the same concept.