# Firebase creator of room becomes admin of that room

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

As mentioned in the title, I want to allow the user that created the room to become an admin of that room, allowing him to update the details of that room or invite other users.I have gone through some database security rules tutorial and I still don't understand how it works. The closest thing i have found is this link:

[Defining the User roles in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236163/defining-the-user-roles-in-firebase)

I tried and it still couldn't work, do i need so make a new table or something? Can someone explain to me how it works or how do I achieve it?[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShP6L.png)

EDITED 1:
Added Main and Add activity

EDITED 2:
Added Team and TeamList class

AddActivity

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

EditText editTextName;
Spinner spinnerSport;
Button buttonAddTeam;

List<Team> teams;

DatabaseReference databaseTeams;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){

        finish();

        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
    }

    databaseTeams = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teams");

    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    spinnerSport = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSports);

    buttonAddTeam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddTeam);

    teams = new ArrayList<>();


    buttonAddTeam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            addTeam();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(AddActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
}



private void addTeam() {

    String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    String sport = spinnerSport.getSelectedItem().toString();

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    user.getUid();

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {

        String id = databaseTeams.push().getKey();
        String owner = user.getUid();

        Team team = new Team(id, name, sport, owner);

        databaseTeams.child(id).setValue(team);

        editTextName.setText("");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Team added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String TEAM_NAME = "com.example.user.stfv2.teamname";
public static final String TEAM_ID = "com.example.user.stfv2.teamid";

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

EditText editTextName;
Spinner spinnerSport;
Button buttonAddTeam;
ListView listViewTeams;


List<Team> teams;


DatabaseReference databaseTeams;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){

        finish();

        startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
    }


    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    databaseTeams = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teams");


    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    spinnerSport = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerSports);
    listViewTeams = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTeams);

    buttonAddTeam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddTeam);


    teams = new ArrayList<>();


    buttonAddTeam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    AddActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });


    listViewTeams.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Team team = teams.get(i);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TeamActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra(TEAM_ID, team.getTeamId());
            intent.putExtra(TEAM_NAME, team.getTeamName());


            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    listViewTeams.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Team team = teams.get(i);
            showUpdateDeleteDialog(team.getTeamId(), team.getTeamName());
            return true;
        }
    });


}

private void showUpdateDeleteDialog(final String teamId, String teamName) {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_dialog, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    final EditText editTextName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    final Spinner spinnerSport = (Spinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSports);
    final Button buttonUpdate = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdateTeam);
    final Button buttonDelete = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDeleteTeam);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle(teamName);
    final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
    b.show();


    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
            String sport = spinnerSport.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String owner = user.getUid();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                updateTeam(teamId, name, sport, owner);
                b.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });


    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            deleteTeam(teamId);
            b.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

private boolean updateTeam(String id, String name, String sport, String owner) {

    DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teams").child(id);


    Team team = new Team(id, name, sport, owner);
    dR.setValue(team);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Team Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}

private boolean deleteTeam(String id) {

    DatabaseReference dR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("teams").child(id);


    dR.removeValue();


    DatabaseReference drTracks = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tracks").child(id);


    drTracks.removeValue();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Team Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseTeams.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            teams.clear();


            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Team team = postSnapshot.getValue(Team.class);

                teams.add(team);
            }


            TeamList teamAdapter = new TeamList(MainActivity.this, teams);

            listViewTeams.setAdapter(teamAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_logout:

            firebaseAuth.signOut();

            finish();

            startActivity(new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}


}
```

Team.java:

```
package com.example.user.stfv2;

import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class Team {
private String teamId;
private String teamName;
private String teamSport;
private String teamOwner;


public Team(String teamId, String teamName, String teamSport, String teamOwner) {
    this.teamId = teamId;
    this.teamName = teamName;
    this.teamSport = teamSport;
    this.teamOwner = teamOwner;
}

public String getTeamId() {return teamId;}

public String getTeamName() {
    return teamName;
}

public String getTeamSport() {
    return teamSport;
}
//this method is never used, i don't know where to use it
public String getTeamOwner() { return  teamOwner; }
}
```

TeamList.java

```
public class TeamList extends ArrayAdapter<Team> {
private Activity context;
List<Team> teams;

public TeamList(Activity context, List<Team> teams) {
    super(context, R.layout.layout_team_list, teams);
    this.context = context;
    this.teams = teams;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_team_list, null, true);

    TextView textViewName = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    TextView textViewSport = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewSport);

    Team team = teams.get(position);
    textViewName.setText(team.getTeamName());
    textViewSport.setText(team.getTeamSport());

    return listViewItem;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your room only has one admin you can use this. With `$uid` being the uid of the user that created the room.

db structure:

```
root: {
  sportsteamfinder: {
    teams: {
      $team: {
        teamId: $team,
        teamOwner: $uid,
        teamName: henq,
        teamSport: Football
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "sportsteamfinder": {
      "teams": {
        "$team": {
          ".write": "data.child('teamOwner').val() === auth.uid || !data.exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Or,** if you want multiple admins per room. Again with $uid and $uid2 being the ID's of the admins.

db structure:

```
root: {
  sportsteamfinder: {
    teams: {
      $team: {
        teamId: $team,
        teamAdmins: {
          $uid: true,
          $uid2: true
        },
        teamName: henq,
        teamSport: Football
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "sportsteamfinder": {
      "teams": {
        "$team": {
          ".write": "data.child('teamAdmins/'+auth.uid).exists() || !data.exists()"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you know how to save user's UID into database like the structure you mention? I want to store the creator's uid the moment he creates the team. I've tried to search for answer and mostly are just for when user first login. Really sorry for the trouble as I'm still new to firebase. >_<

Comment: On web you'd get it via `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`. I don't know what you're developing in so I can't give you an exact answer. You can find your answer in the Firebase docs. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: `FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();` That will give you the current signed in user, or null, if no one is signed in. And this `user.getUid()` will then give you his UID. Save that UID in the Team class and store that in the database under teamOwner.

Comment: I also edited my answer to include `!data.exists()` to allow anyone to write if the room doesn't exist yet

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I tried to add uid into my database and so far I have succeeded, however my MainActivity can't read the data from database now and my app will proceed to crash. Please help me fix it, to be honest I'm not even sure whether i use the correct method to add uid into database. Again really sorry for the inconvenience caused because of my lack of experience.

Comment: Where does it crash? At what line?

Comment: MainActivity, line 211 i think

Comment: I can't see line numbers ;) Is it on `Team team = postSnapshot.getValue(Team.class);` ?

Comment: yes, 
at com.example.user.stfv2.MainActivity$6.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:211)
there's only this link in the logcat, so probably it

Comment: I don't know, maybe because you don't have an empty constructor `public Team() {}` but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you put the whole errormessage in your question, that'll make it easier?

Comment: Omg its really the empty constructor, thanks man :)


Edit:
I tried your rules and I cant create or delete teams regardless of which uid i signed in with.

Comment: Are you writing to teams/$team?

Comment: Yes, I simply copy the first rules you provided, or is it something wrong with how i store UID? I'm not sure I'm using the correct way

Comment: Everything seems fine, is it an error or 'Permission denied'?

Comment: permission denied

Listen at /teams failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

setValue at /teams/-KfBqrvn1q4AVeEtNj3p failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Comment: Seems like you're pushing to /teams/id, whereas the rules are set up for /sportsteamfinder/teams/id. Also you'll have to add a ".read": true  rule to make sure you can read data.

Comment: Alright I got it!!! Really thank you man for all the answers and efforts you put in here. Really thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can accept my answer if it helped you.